# Unable to run SQL Powershell using Agent account

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012, database-administration

In a SQL server in my environment, couple of days after patch(Not immediately after), syspolicy purge job started failing at step 3 executing powershell. When I created a test job with a simple print statement that is not working as well. If i create a Proxy with my account and run the job it suceeds. The agent account is a domain account with both local admin and sysadmin permissions on SQL server. I'm not sure why it crashes with the below error message everytime it calls powershell.

```
Application popup error - SQLPS.exe The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot it is!! Whew! There aint anything wrong with the Agent account. Something with the agent account was broke! Glad the issue is resolved.

Note:: The server was rebooted after the patch and there was no pending reboot. Also, after patching the job ran successfully 2 days. So just a weird failure! I'm unable to find what broke the account.